# How to execute Scitools Understand commands from python

Tags: python, shell, terminal, scitools, scitools-understand

I want to execute Scitools Understand commands from python. It has its own shell which can be run using `$ ./und` and switches to `und>`. I want to run its commands from python. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should consider using the Python API for Ada Understand. This will be more comfortable than talking to the Understand console.

But using the console application is also possible. Ada Understand uses the standard input and output. Assuming you use Linux I have just a small demonstration for this.

create a file und.input with the contents

```
help
exit
```

And then exeucute this command

```
cat und.input | /opt/scitools/bin/linux64/und > und.output
```

This will create you the output into the file und.output.

You will not do it through files. With these files I just tried to give you evidence and a feeling that really the standard input and standard output is used. Knowing this, you need a way in Python to start a process and communicate to it over stdin and stdout. The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is a way to implement this. But there may be alternatives.

Although my demonstration above is on Linux, the Python implementation with subprocess will be the same for Windows.

Comment: Thanks. The its python API included in their own python interpreter named upython which is buggy, i.e. can not be included into vscode, it is working in terminal though.

Comment: Using upython is only one option. You can also use your own Python installation. See [here](https://support.scitools.com/support/solutions/articles/70000582852-getting-started-with-the-python-api).
Your Understand installation may not have all the Python files. In my installation they are missing. I don't know why. Maybe my version is too old. But in general it should work, as the manual says so. So you should again have a look.